# ¿Como puedo hacer un FOR con variables dinamicas con twig?

Tags: php, bucle-for, twig, slim

Estoy trabajando con twig, migrando un desarrollo que tenía hecho anteriormente.
Me he topado con la necesidad de hacer un bucle for que en php lo hacía algo así:

```
<?php 
for($x=$this->inid;$x<$this->find;$x++){
   //TODO 
} 
?>
```

Como pueden ver estoy tomando las variables `inid` y `find` del objeto que tengo. Los datos ya los obtengo con twig pero no tengo idea de como realizar este bucle con twig y la documentación no me logra dar una solucion especifica, ya que en esta se itera siempre sobre un array, algo como:

```
{% for user in users %}
   <li>{{ user.username|e }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Pero este no es mi caso.

He intentado esto,

```
{% set inicio = tpl.inid %}
{% set final = tpl.find %}
{% for x in inicio..final +%}
  {{ x }}
{% endfor %}
```

pero obtengo el error:

> Type: Twig\Error\SyntaxError
>   Message: Unexpected token "end of statement block" of value "".
>   File: C:\xampp\htdocs\contablenift2\templates\informes\BalanceDePrueba.phtml
>   Line: 29

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo utilizaría `range`

```
{% set incio = tpl.inid %}
{% set final = tpl.find %}

{% for i in range(inicio, final) %}
<tr>
    <td>{{tuarraray[i]}}</td> 
    <td>posición {{i}}</td>
<tr>
{% endfor %}
```

[Documentación](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/functions/range.html)